# Model properties in Ruby on Rails views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How to use model's properties at Rubi on Rails' views?

My model:

```
class EntryItems < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :created_on, :updated_on, :activity_type, :date_from, :date_to
  attr_protected :user_id, :from_tyear, :from_tmonth, :from_tday

  @@date_from = nil

  def date_from
    @@date_from = Date.new(read_attribute(:from_tyear), read_attribute(:from_tmonth), read_attribute(:from_tday))
  end

  def date_from=(date_from_value)
    if date_from_value.is_a?(Time)
      @@date_from = date_from_value.to_date
    end
    write_attribute(:from_tyear, date_from_value.year)
    write_attribute(:from_tmonth, date_from_value.mon)
    write_attribute(:from_tday, date_from_value.mday)
  end
end
```

My controller:

```
class ItemEntriesSetupController < ApplicationController
  unloadable

  def index
    @item_entry = DayoffEntries.new(:user => User.current, :created_on => Time.now, :updated_on => Time.now)
    @item_entry_post_url = url_for(:controller => 'item_entries_setup', :action => 'update')
  end

  def update
  #code is skipped
  end
end
```

My view:

```
<%= form_tag(@item_entry_post_url) do %>
  <dl>
    <label>Issues:</label> 
    <%=date_field_tag 'date_from', true, @item_entry.date_from %>
  </dl>
  <%= submit_tag(l(:button_create)) %>
<% end %>
```

It fails with `underfined method 'div' for nil:NilClass`.

What do I do wrong?

(I'm really new in Ruby on Rails, so I still have problems with finding right practicies, because there're plenty of code examples written n different style).

Comment: plz exlian your question what you want to do ????

Comment: The problem is not in the code you have shown here. Try to find the bad code. Watch error backtrace input.

Comment: I'm going to create a form to create EntryItems.

Looks like @item_entry is counted as nil. I can't understand why, when I do inspect, it shows just fields, not properties.

Comment: why are you using @@date_from, why not @date_from? @@date_from is static variable for class, @date_from is for the object

Comment: Please explain what actually you are trying to do?